# gulp task throwing error on second time run

Tags: gulp

I have two folders both of which contain some html template files. I need to minify these files to separate folders.

folder structure

```
|src
|--clientTemplates
|----abc.html
|----xyz.html
|--serverTemplates
|----abc.html
|----xyz.html
```

required destination folder

```
|dist
|--client
|----abc.html
|----xyz.html
|--server
|----abc.html
|----xyz.html
```

following is my gulpfile where I have my tasks defined for the

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var del = require('del');
var minOptions = {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    minifyJS: { output: { quote_style: 1 } },
    minifyCSS: true
};    

gulp.task('clean', function(done) {
    del(['dist'], done());
});

gulp.task('minify:serverTemplates', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('src/serverTemplates/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin(minOptions))
        .pipe(replace('\\', '\\\\'))
        .pipe(replace('"', '\\"'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/server'));
});

gulp.task('minify:clientTemplates', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('src/clientTemplates/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin(minOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/client'));
});

gulp.task(
    'default',
    gulp.series('clean', 'minify:serverTemplates', 'minify:clientTemplates', function inSeries(done) {
        done();
    })
);
```

when I run the gulp command it works fine for the first time, but throws errors on alternate runs.
running gulp command first time
[image: running gulp command first time- output]

running gulp command second time
[image: running gulp command second time- output]

can't figure out what exactly is wrong there.
Also is there a way to run the two minification task parallel once the clean task has finished?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the error disappear when you change your clean task to `gulp.task('clean', function() { return del(['dist']); });`?

Comment: @TheDancingCode.... thanks dude, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you pass to `del` is wrong. Just return the promise:

```js
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del(['dist']);
});
```

As for running the minification tasks in parallel, use `gulp.parallel`:

```js
gulp.task(
  'default',
  gulp.series(
    'clean',
    gulp.parallel('minify:serverTemplates', 'minify:clientTemplates')
  )
);
```